# xcolor command `\color` stops working in xelatex

Tags: xetex, color

Test program:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\color{red}1
\color{blue}0
... many lines ...
\color{red}1
\color{blue}0
\end{document}
```

Test result:

Only first few lines are correctly colored. The rest is all blue.

Using `\textcolor{...}{...}` seems OK, but not with `\color{...}`.

The above code is MWE, with 200 repeats (400 lines) of 1 and 0. The bug appears when processed with `xelatex` but not `pdflatex`.

Comment: Do you have a MWE that reproduces this problem? What’s the minimum number of lines for it to appear? Does it depend on the engine?

Comment: @Davislor MWE contains 200 repeats, so 400 lines of interleaving 1 and 0.

Comment: @Davislor And it seems the bug only appears in xelatex not pdflatex.

Comment: Maybe there is some other error. The example given compiles in PdfTex and XeLatex without error. Maybe a closed segment will eliminate what appears for when compiled, for example `\color{purple}{... many lines ...}`.

Comment: @Leucippus The code doesn't raise errors, but the color stack overflows and the colour doesn't change anymore. Compile the example in my answer with pdfTeX and XeTeX to see the diffrerence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xdvipdfmx`, the PDF driver for XeTeX, has a limited colour stack. Each time you use (say) `\color{red}`, it does `\special{color push rgb 1 0 0}` to push a colour to the stack, but since you don't end a group anywhere, that colour stays on the stack indefinitely (no `\special{color pop}` happens).

The `xelatex` program has an arguably bad default of running `xdvipdfmx` with `-q`, so that type of issue doesn't show up (because it isn't detected during the TeX run). If you run `xelatex` with `xelatex --output-driver='xdvipdfmx' <file>.tex`, then it will tell you:

```
xdvipdfmx:warning: Color stack overflow. Just ignore.
```

You need to use `\color` inside a group, or do `\reset@color` manually.

Here's a sample code that shows that:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcount\cnta
\begin{document}
\loop
\color{red}\the\cnta\space
\advance\cnta1
\color{blue}\the\cnta\par
\advance\cnta1
\ifnum\cnta<150
\repeat
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does the `\reset@color` command do? Pop 1 color from the stack?

Comment: @Cyker Yes, `\reset@color` is (in XeTeX) `\special{color pop}`. Colours don't obey TeX's grouping, so `{\special{color push rgb 1 0 0} hello} world` prints both words red because there's no `\special{color pop}`.  But `\color{red}` does `\special{color push rgb 1 0 0}\aftergroup\reset@color`, so this emulates grouping effect on colours.